Having issue with getting id which is mapped to objectid when grouped
 CREATE TABLE Candidate (
  
  runId  bigint,
  objectId bigint,
  name VARCHAR(100)
  
);



INSERT INTO Candidate(runId, objectId, name) VALUES (1, 401, 'object1');
INSERT INTO Candidate(runId, objectId, name) VALUES (1, 402, 'object2');
INSERT INTO Candidate(runId, objectId, name) VALUES (1, 403, 'object3');
INSERT INTO Candidate(runId, objectId, name) VALUES (1, 404, 'object4');
INSERT INTO Candidate(runId, objectId, name) VALUES (2, 401, 'object1');
INSERT INTO Candidate(runId, objectId, name) VALUES (2, 402, 'object2');
INSERT INTO Candidate(runId, objectId, name) VALUES (2, 403, 'object3');
INSERT INTO Candidate(runId, objectId, name) VALUES (2, 404, 'object4');
INSERT INTO Candidate(runId, objectId, name) VALUES (2, 405, 'object5');
INSERT INTO Candidate(runId, objectId, name) VALUES (2, 406, 'object6');
INSERT INTO Candidate(runId, objectId, name) VALUES (2, 406, 'object7');

Query Data as a CTE:
Proposed



Objectid
name




401
'object1'


402
'object2'


403
'object3'


404
'object4'



  SELECT c.runid
  FROM candidate c
  INNER JOIN proposed p ON c.objectid = p.objectid AND c.name = p.name
  GROUP BY c.runid
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.objectid) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM proposed);

Output:



runid




1


2



Expected Output



runid




1



Candidate is already existing record in db. I have created Proposed CTE from the data that is coming through query. I want to map the objectid, name equal to candidate.objectid, candidate.name. The runId that is linked has to have same number of records as proposed where p.objectid=c.objectid and p.name=c.name. In the candidate table runid shouldn't have extra or less records linked to that runId.

This looks to be a Relational Division Without Remainder question. Your existing solution is almost right. It is doing With Remainder.
Just change INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN, and add an extra condition to check that all rows matched.
The logic is as follows:

If you inner-join then the COUNT(*) will only include rows of candidate that actually match. It will therefore always match either With or Without Remainder sets.
Whereas if you left-join then you are asking for all rows in candidate. Then you need that to be the exact number of rows as proposed.
And we also use COUNT(*) = COUNT(p.objectid) which tells us that all rows in the set had a match, in other words there are no extra rows.

SELECT c.runid
FROM candidate c
LEFT JOIN proposed p ON c.objectid = p.objectid AND c.name = p.name
GROUP BY c.runid
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM proposed)
   AND COUNT(*) = COUNT(p.objectid);

db<>fiddle

Thank you very much. And thank you for explaining what's wrong.

The solution fails to consider when there could be number of matching count rows but rows not containing matching objectid, name. I have provided new case in the fiddle. The expected output should be 1. But its showing 1,3
https://dbfiddle.uk/zmxXLnuF

You're right, see edit
